# What's the value proposition of running Cloud Run versus a normal service in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

Is there any advantage if I use Cloud Run instead of deploying a normal service/container in GKE?

Answer (score 8):

I will try to add my perspective.

This answer does not cover running containers in Google Cloud Run Kubernetes. The reason is that we wanted an almost zero cost solution for a legacy PHP website. Cloud Run fit perfectly and we had an easy time both porting the code and learning Cloud Run.

We needed to do something with a legacy PHP website. This website was running on Windows Server 2012, IIS and PHP 7.0x. The cost was over $100.00 per month - mostly for Windows licensing fees for a VM in the cloud. The site was not accessed very much but was needed for various business reasons.

A decision was made Thursday (4/18/2019) was that we needed to learn Google Cloud Run, so we decided to port this site to a container and try to run the container in Google Cloud. Nothing like a real world example to learn the details.

Friday, we ported the PHP code to Apache. Very easy process. We did not worry about SSL as we intend to use Cloud Run SSL.

Saturday we started to learn Cloud Run. Within an hour we had the Hello World PHP example running. [Link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy).

Within two hours we had the containerized website running in Cloud Run. Again, very simple.

Then we learned how to configure Cloud Run SSL with our DNS server.

End result:

1. Almost zero cost for a PHP website running in Cloud Run.
2. Approximately 1.5 days of effort to port the legacy code and learn Cloud Run.
3. Savings of about $100.00 per month (no Windows IIS server).
4. We do not have to worry about SSL certificates from now on for this site.

For small websites that are static, Cloud Run is a killer product. The learning curve is very small even if you do not know Google Cloud. You just need to configure gcloud for container builds and deployment. This means developers can be independant of needing to master GCP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I very much agree with you on how it is going to be a game changer if you just ran it and let Google handle your cluster. The amount of removing complexity alone _is_ game changing. I think that's the value of serverless, Google just remove the flexibility barrier of serverless with this product (pre-baked runtime). While it's still in beta, it holds a lot of promise.

What I'm interested in, is if you already have a GKE cluster, and you deploy your containers normally. What advantage would you get if you change your deployment to a Cloud Run service.

Comment: Cloud Run and Cloud Run Kubernetes is the same. Except for Cloud Run Kubernetes has fewing limitations (at this time) - support for VPC, Cloud SQL, etc.. For Cloud Run Kubernetes, you use the same commands to deploy as Cloud Run. This is a big deal for developers that do not know Kubernetes.

Answer (score 7):

There are many distinctions in using Cloud Run to expose a service as compared to running it natively in GKE.  The primary of these is that Cloud Run provides more of a serverless infrastructure.  Basically you declare that you want to expose a service and then let GCP do the rest.  Contrast this with creating a Kubernetes cluster and then defining your service in pods.  With a manually created GKE cluster, the nodes and environment are *always on* which means that you are billed for them regardless of utilization.  With Cloud Run, your service is merely available and you are only billed for actual consumption.  If your service not being called, your costs are zero.  Another advantage is that you don't have to predict your utilization needs and allocate sufficient nodes.  Scaling happens automatically for you.

See also these presentations from Google Next 19:

- [Migrating from a Monolith to Microservices (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPfsMKeBzJU)
- [What's New in Serverless Compute? (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zfnhg1wneiA)
- [Run Containers on GCP's Serverless Infrastructure (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVuuvZkYiNM)
- [Run Cloud Functions Everywhere (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMEcyAkTliU)
- [Container Once, Serverless Anywhere (Cloud Next '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16vANkKxoAU)

Comment: while your answer holds true vs Cloud Run vs Cloud Run on GKE, my question was what's the difference between Cloud Run on GKE versus running your deployment normally.

Comment: Howdy @chriz ... I guess I am not following the notion of what we mean by running the REST server app "normally"?  Can you elaborate on what you mean by running it normally?  I had assumed that had meant building a container which actively listens on a TCP port for incoming REST requests and servicing them when they arrived and deploying that container in a POD in the way that one would normally deploy pods.

Comment: That’s it exactly, what’s the advantage if having a deployment in Cloud Run versus a normal pod that’s not. Cloud Run is basically another kind if deployment.

Comment: Imagine if I am given a container that services REST requests that was built by a separate development team.  I want to run that container as a black box and not worry about what is in it.  My goal now is to run this container.  You are 100% correct in thinking I can run this with "normal" Kubernetes or I can run it with Cloud Run.   But notice something interesting ... with Cloud Run the complexity of getting it running was close to zero.

Comment: yes, but I'm specifically asking about the 2nd flavor of Cloud Run, which is Cloud Run for GKE, what's the advantage of running my container as a normal pod versus running it as Cloud Run on GKE? There's also a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler in Kubernetes with vanilla deployment, which is similar how Cloud Run scale?

Comment: Ahh ... lightbulb.  I didn't get that from your original question.  My understanding is that Cloud Run deploying to GKE is merely "assistance" in leveraging the concept of "Knative Serving".  What I'd suggest is that we wrap our minds around the Knative specification/functions and specifically Knative Serving.  Once we get those concepts under our belt then we find that Cloud Run deployment on GKE is  no more/no less than a shortcut to leverage Knative Serving without having to perform manual definitions.  So if one believes in Knative, Cloud Run for GKE becomes a quick deployment for that.

Comment: yeah, right now there's nothing to configure in Cloud Run UI not sure if you can edit the deployment yaml and able to customize Knative at will, I guess that's possible, but for the UI, I only see domain mapping and creating a service.