# How is Google's Cloud Run different from a traditional Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I was thinking of testing out Google's Cloud Run for a simple app when all of a sudden I got thinking as to whether Cloud Run is basically a managed K8s cluster. I really wanted to know as to when using Cloud Run would be preferred over traditional K8s clusters and why we should prefer it?

Thanks.

Comment: Could your question be a duplicate of .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786955/whats-the-value-proposition-of-running-cloud-run-versus-a-normal-service-in-gke/55787525

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the value proposition of running Cloud Run versus a normal service in GKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786955/whats-the-value-proposition-of-running-cloud-run-versus-a-normal-service-in-gke)

Comment: How well do you know Kubernetes? If very little, use Cloud Run or invest heavily in training yourself. Do you have a cluster already deployed? If not, Cloud Run is a cost-effective solution. Kubernetes is a wonderful platform if you know what you are doing but the learning curve is often very high. Cloud Run is brain dead simple.

Answer (score 4):

Technology wise, cloud Run is a managed Kubernetes cluster with Knative to run the containers on top of it.

However Cloud Run brings an additional advantages when you run fully managed: you only pay for used resources. In other words, Cloud Run can do scale down to zero cost, rather than bottoming out at the cost of keeping a minimum sized cluster running.